# jquery setInterval and setTimeout not working

Tags: jquery

i am stuck here...i am trying to inactive a button for 5 sec after per click...
i can inactive the button but having trouble while bringing it back
i tried bith setIntervel and setTimeout

```
     function reverser(){
       $(this).css("background","url(images/btn_active.gif) no-repeat 0 0");
   }


      $(".vtbtn").click(function() {  
       var link =$(this).attr('id');
           $(this).css("background","url(images/btn_inactive.gif) no-repeat 0 0");  
          $.ajax({  
              type: "POST",  
              url: "sql.php",  
              data:"voted=" +link+"&user="+<?php echo $userId;?>,  
              success: function(data){  
              setInterval('reverser()',3000);
              } 
          }); 


});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is probably not defined, try:

```
function reverser(){
   $(".vtbtn").css("background","url(images/btn_active.gif) no-repeat 0 0");
}
```

And then call the function like so:

```
setInterval(reverser, 3000);
```

And do you really need to run that function every three seconds, is'nt it enough to just run after the Ajax call is completed?

Comment: What if there are more than one elements with the class of `vtbtn`?

Comment: thanks it works...but why $(this) function not working while it does in my 1st fuction?..i think i got it..

Comment: Then the element will have to be passed on in the function.

Comment: `$(this)` is defined by the function called on the element, the second function is not called on a specific element, so `this` has no context.

Comment: If using more than one element with the same class, and targeting a specific element, you will have to do what @RichardDalton says, and pass the element along in the function call.

Comment: $(this).css("background","url(images/btn_inactive.gif) no-repeat 0 0"); 
          $.ajax({  
              type: "POST",  
              url: "sql.php",  
              data:"voted=" +link+"&user="+<?php echo $userId;?>,  
              success: function(data){  
        setInterval(function(){
    $(".vtbtn").css("background","url(images/btn_active.gif) no-repeat 0 0");},5000);
} 
}); 
});

Comment: Yes, you can also remove the reverser function and just do it in the success function instead, no problem! Maybe consider doing it in the Ajax error handler aswell, or using the complete handler, so your button returns if something goes wrong with the Ajax call.

Comment: so is there is any way to inherit $(this) in nested functions?like this 1          :$(this).css("background","url(images/btn_inactive.gif) no-repeat 0 0"); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "sql.php", data:"voted=" +link+"&user="+<?php echo $userId;?>, success: function(data){ setInterval(function(){ $(this).css("background","url(images/btn_active.gif) no-repeat 0 0");},5000); } }); });

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your reverser function does not refer to the element that was clicked. Change your code to pass in that element instead:

```
function reverser(ele){
   $(ele).css("background","url(images/btn_active.gif) no-repeat 0 0");
}

$(".vtbtn").click(function() {  
      var link =$(this).attr('id');
      var that = this; // save this
      $(that).css("background","url(images/btn_inactive.gif) no-repeat 0 0");  
      $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "sql.php",  
          data:"voted=" +link+"&user="+<?php echo $userId;?>,  
          success: function(data){  
              setTimeout(function() { 
                  reverser(that); 
              },3000);
          } 
      }); 
});
```

I changed it so that setTimeout is passed a function rather than a string (which will result in a call to `eval`, which is evil) so that the `that` variable can be passed into the `resverser` function.